# Synchronize read/unread status for Thunderbird RSS

Tags: sync, thunderbird, rss

I've tried several online [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) readers, but I didn't like any of them. I'm quite happy with [Thunderbird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird), but I hate to have to manually mark as read articles I've read at home when I'm at work and vice versa.

Is there a way to synchronize the status of read/unread articles between Thunderbird installations?

Answer (score 1):

You could synchronize the profile folders using e.g. rsync.

But there is not, to my knowledge, a way for two running (or worse, not-running) TB instances to synchronize with each other.